# I want to update my tableview static cells, how I can update it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a Tableview Controller, in that there are 9 rows are there. All are static rows, 
and in row having counts of tickets, so I want to update it dynamically, whenever data changes in that data also want to change here,also I want to update image. So How I can do it...!

It updates but, every time we have to build it..then values count will update..! SO following screen shot..!

[This is an screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GWhM.jpg)

```
    #import "LeftMenuViewController.h"
        #import "RKDropdownAlert.h"
        #import "HexColors.h"
        #import "AppConstanst.h"
        #import "GlobalVariables.h"
        #import "MyWebservices.h"
        #import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>

        @import Firebase;
        @interface LeftMenuViewController (){
             NSUserDefaults *userDefaults;
           GlobalVariables *globalVariables;
            }
          @end

          @implementation LeftMenuViewController

          - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
          {
             self.slideOutAnimationEnabled = YES;

             return [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
           }

         - (void)viewDidLoad {
             [super viewDidLoad];

              NSLog(@"Naaa-LeftMENU");

            self.tableView.tableFooterView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];


           }



           -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

                 userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
               globalVariables=[GlobalVariables sharedInstance];
                NSLog(@"Role : %@",[userDefaults objectForKey:@"role"]);
             _user_role.text=[[userDefaults objectForKey:@"role"] uppercaseString];

            _user_nameLabel.text=[userDefaults objectForKey:@"profile_name"];
           _url_label.text=[userDefaults objectForKey:@"baseURL"];

            [_user_profileImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"profile_pic"]]
                          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"default_pic.png"]];
            _user_profileImage.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor hx_colorWithHexRGBAString:@"#0288D1"] CGColor];

              _user_profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = _user_profileImage.frame.size.height /2;
          _user_profileImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            _user_profileImage.layer.borderWidth = 0;



            NSInteger open =  [globalVariables.OpenCount integerValue];
            NSInteger closed = [globalVariables.ClosedCount integerValue];
            NSInteger trash = [globalVariables.DeletedCount integerValue];
            NSInteger unasigned = [globalVariables.UnassignedCount integerValue];
           NSInteger my_tickets = [globalVariables.MyticketsCount integerValue];

    if(open>999){
        _inbox_countLabel.text=@"999+";
    }else
        _inbox_countLabel.text=@(open).stringValue;
    if(closed>999){
        _closed_countLabel.text=@"999+";
    }else
        _closed_countLabel.text=@(closed).stringValue;
    if(trash>999){
        _trash_countLabel.text=@"999+";
    }else
        _trash_countLabel.text=@(trash).stringValue;
    if(unasigned>999){
        _unassigned_countLabel.text=@"999+";
    }else
        _unassigned_countLabel.text=@(unasigned).stringValue;
    if(my_tickets>999){
        _myTickets_countLabel.text=@"999+";
    }else
        _myTickets_countLabel.text=@(my_tickets).stringValue;
    [self.tableView reloadData];

     }

        - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
         [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
           // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
         }


        - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
             UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                             bundle: nil];

          // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

         UIViewController *vc ;

    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 1:
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"CreateTicket"];
            break;

        case 2:
            [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
            break;
        case 3:
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"InboxID"];
            break;
        case 4:
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"MyTicketsID"];
            break;
        case 5:
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"UnassignedTicketsID"];
            break;
        case 6:
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ClosedTicketsID"];
            break;

        case 7:
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"TrashTicketsID"];
            break;

        case 8:
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ClientListID"];
            break;

        case 10:
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"AboutVCID"];
            break;


        case 11:

            [self wipeDataInLogout];
            //[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:YES];
            //[[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

            [RKDropdownAlert title:@"Faveo Helpdesk" message:@"You've logged out, successfully." backgroundColor:[UIColor hx_colorWithHexRGBAString:SUCCESS_COLOR] textColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"Login"];
            // (vc.view.window!.rootViewController?).dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil);
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }

    [[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] popToRootAndSwitchToViewController:vc
                                                             withSlideOutAnimation:self.slideOutAnimationEnabled
                                                                     andCompletion:nil];
}

          - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:
              (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
           {

          if (indexPath.row == 9) {
              return 0;
             } else {
        return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

}

       -(void)wipeDataInLogout{

    [self sendDeviceToken];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    // get documents path
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    // get the path to our Data/plist file
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"faveoData.plist"];
    NSError *error;
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:plistPath error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error while removing the plist %@", error.localizedDescription);
        //TODO: Handle/Log error
    }

    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *each in cookieStorage.cookies) {
        [cookieStorage deleteCookie:each];
       }

    }

         -(void)sendDeviceToken{

   // NSUserDefaults *userDefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@fcmtoken?user_id=%@&fcm_token=%s&os=%@",[userDefaults objectForKey:@"companyURL"],[userDefaults objectForKey:@"user_id"],"0",@"ios"];
    MyWebservices *webservices=[MyWebservices sharedInstance];
    [webservices httpResponsePOST:url parameter:@"" callbackHandler:^(NSError *error,id json,NSString* msg){
        if (error || [msg containsString:@"Error"]) {
            if (msg) {

                // [utils showAlertWithMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error-%@",msg] sendViewController:self];
                NSLog(@"Thread-postAPNS-toserver-error == %@",error.localizedDescription);
            }else if(error)  {
                //                [utils showAlertWithMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error-%@",error.localizedDescription] sendViewController:self];
                NSLog(@"Thread-postAPNS-toserver-error == %@",error.localizedDescription);
            }
            return ;
        }
        if (json) {

            NSLog(@"Thread-sendAPNS-token-json-%@",json);
        }

    }];
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // rows in section 0 should not be selectable
    // if ( indexPath.section == 0 ) return nil;

    // first 3 rows in any section should not be selectable
    if ( (indexPath.row ==0) || (indexPath.row==2) ) return nil;

    // By default, allow row to be selected
    return indexPath;
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1):

In summary of your question is you need a logic to reload single cell.

Here is your solutions. **You need to know index of row of cell which you need to reload.**

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: rowNumber, section: 0)
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
```

Comment: I will try it..! But this code where I have to write ??

Comment: From where you to reload the cell

Comment: @MallikarjunHanagandi did you try with my answer?